# duplicate classes or library dependency conflicts

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have a problem 'duplicate class' build failed don't know actually how to resolve the class conflicts i had tried navigate(from UI)=> class=>multiple libraries shown but don't know how to resolve

Duplicate class `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

found in modules classes.jar (`com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0`)

and classes.jar (`com.android.support:design:24.0.0`)

error shown in BuildOutPut

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  ....
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
 ...
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
}
```

project/build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

Look here what is the error shown in android studio
   [library dependency conflict or duplicate class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542106/library-dependency-conflict-or-duplicate-class)

Comment: did n't resolved

Comment: @ Zoe, Stephen C please revisit my question i think